> Task :react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
I am trying to build an RN android project. This issue does not reproduce on Debian. I tried to install libs like: wget, nano, unzip, libunwind-dev, git-lfs, gnupg, bash, build-base, cmake, ninja, libc6-compat, libtool, autoconf, automake, g++, python3, py3-pip, libstdc++, gcompat, libgcc, coreutils, curl. Did not help.
My build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 30
        compileSdkVersion = 34 
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
    }

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1428] exception while building Json A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/1f364v4o/logs/arm64-v8a/prefab_command'' : org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/1f364v4o/logs/arm64-v8a/prefab_command''
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.execExceptionFor(DefaultExecHandle.java:241)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:218)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:396)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.lambda$run$3(ExecHandleRunner.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:101)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
  Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start '/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/1f364v4o/logs/arm64-v8a/prefab_command'
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.startProcess(ExecHandleRunner.java:122)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.lambda$run$0(ExecHandleRunner.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:79)
        ... 5 more
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/1f364v4o/logs/arm64-v8a/prefab_command" (in directory "/usr/src/app/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android"): error=8, Exec format error
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 9 more
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=8, Exec format error
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
        ... 11 more

